# Script em Json com problema, Google Chrome bloqueia e não funciona em outro navegado

Tags: javascript, json, script

Estou tentado fazer um auto preenchimento de dados a partir do CEP, com o seguinte código.

```js
$("#cep").blur(function() {
  var cep = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
  if (cep.length != 8) {
    return false;
  }

  var url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";

  $.getJSON(url, function(dadosRetorno) {
    try {
      $("#endereco").val(dadosRetorno.logradouro);
      $("#bairro").val(dadosRetorno.bairro);
      $("#cidade").val(dadosRetorno.localidade);
      $("#uf").val(dadosRetorno.uf);
    } catch (ex) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <label id="nome">CEP</label>
  <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <label id="nome">Endereço</label>
  <input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <label id="nome">Número</label>
  <input type="number" name="numero" id="numero" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <label id="nome">Bairro</label>
  <input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Mas ele não funciona no Firefox e no Chrome ele da erro que o script inseguro foi bloqueado, mas se eu escolher a opção "Carregar Script inseguro" o script funciona normalmente, tentei em vários computadores e em 2 celulares, e o mesmo problema.

[image: imagem do erro que o Google Chrome aponta]

Alguém já teve esse problema ou algo parecido, e consegue esclarecer um pouco essa duvida???

Comment: Já tentou usar o exemplo que consta na documentação. Usando HTTPS no lugar do HTTP? $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados){}

Comment: Cara, eu testei aqui https://jsfiddle.net/jediWhatever/c4ku0r7p/3/ só mudei o $.getJson por $.get e o https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contar da versão 56, o Chrome [passou a alertar sobre scripts carregados de fontes inseguras](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3118164/google-chrome-to-start-marking-http-connections-as-insecure.html), ou seja, via HTTP.

Para resolver o seu problema, a consulta deveria ser feita utilizando um recurso seguro (HTTPS). No seu código, voce deveria mudar essa linha:

```
var url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";
```

para

```
var url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";
```

O site que você está consumindo a API parece fornecer essa opção. Vide [este exemplo](https://github.com/wgenial/consultacep/blob/master/app.js#L48) utilizando `fetch`.

**EDIT**

Como boa regra em geral, o script do jQuery que você está carregando também deveria deixar explícito o protocolo HTTPS:

Mude

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

para

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Cara deu certo, muito obrigado, ele agora funciona até no Firefox